# SQL server syntax error in update statement, but I can't see it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm getting a syntax error on this query, but I can't figure it out.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'group'.

I believe its on the last group by, but I don't see whats wrong.  Can anyone suggest how to correct this?

```
UPDATE [NCLGS].[dbo].[CP_CustomerShipTo]
SET     TimesUsed = TimesUsed + B.NewCount
from [NCLGS].[dbo].[CP_CustomerShipTo] CST
INNER JOIN (    
    Select
        PKH.CompanyCode, 
        PKH.CompanyName, 
        PKH.Addr1, 
        PKH.Addr2, 
        PKH.City, 
        PKH.State, 
        PKH.Zip, 
        Count(recid) As NewCount
    from avanti_packingslipheader PKH 
    where pksdate > dbo.ufn_StartOfDay(DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE() ) )   
    group by 
        PKH.CompanyCode, 
        PKH.CompanyName, 
        PKH.Addr1, 
        PKH.Addr2, 
        PKH.City, 
        PKH.State, 
        PKH.Zip 
) B 
ON CST.CustomerCode     =   B.CompanyCode
   AND CST.ShipToName       =   B.CompanyName
   AND CST.ShipToAddress1   =   B.Addr1
   AND CST.City             =   B.City
   AND CST.PostalCode       =   B.Zip

group by 
    PKH.CompanyCode, 
    PKH.CompanyName, 
    PKH.Addr1, 
    PKH.Addr2, 
    PKH.City, 
    PKH.State, 
    PKH.Zip
```

BACKGROUND - I'm trying to do an update statement with a Count(), but of course you can't use agg. functions in an update set statement, so I'm trying to use a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the last `Group By`.  What exactly are you hoping this last `group by` will do?

Comment: @Abe Miessler -Thanks for the reformat, @Andriy M beat you to the answer.

Comment: @MAW74656: It was [@Nix](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6513320/2) who reformatted your script actually.

Comment: @Abe: I'm really glad I upvoted your answer *before* seeing your comment.

Comment: Lol, that was meant as a compliment!

Comment: @Andriy M -Ok, I see now.  @Abe Miessler added a tag.  @Nix -Thanks for the format.

Comment: @Abe: Thanks. To be honest, I did suspect as much, and it's good to have it confirmed. :) It's probably the language and my being too sensitive to it. Still, I shouldn't have let it make myself such a display of ingratitude. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You have already got GROUP BY inside the subselect, so what does the outer GROUP BY stand for?

You can't reference an alias in a subselect from an outer GROUP BY. But in any event you can't use GROUP BY with an UPDATE statement, and that's what the error message is about.

Comment: I got lost in my code is what thats about.  I started with a select statement to figure out the where clause (like I usually do), then changed each part until I got the update statement.  Shouldn't do SQL dev with a headache.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this:

```
update mytable set
mycolumn = mycolumn + (select x from ...);
```

Comment: Why?  What is the advantage to this approach over mine?